# Arduino Nano and ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-nano

I am trying to use Arduino Nano with ESP8266 (01). I tried to follow a lot of online tutorial with no result.

In particular this one http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-to-esp8266-serial-commincation/.
I think connections between Arduino Nano and ESP8266 are fine, when I upload the code on Arduino the red led on the ESP8266 turns on, I set the Arduino Monitor to 9600 BAUD and try to send command like "AT" but I got not reply from ESP8266. I also tried to switch to 115200 BAUD with no result too.

I don't if is something wrong or ESP8266 is damaged. Is there any tutorial that you may suggest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Serial Monitor's baud rate must match what you have in

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

The EDP8266's baud rate is specified in the line

```
ESPserial.begin(9600);
```

and that is the one you need to change to try different baud rates with the ESP8266. The newer AIThinker firmwares default to 115200 baud, not 9600 baud.

Be warned, though, that SoftwareSerial isn't that great at 115200 baud - you tend to get some data corruption. It is best to change the baud rate to 9600 baud with

```
AT+CIOBAUD=9600
```

I'd also recommend investing in one of the ESP-01 programming boards from eBay. Make sure you get one of the ones with a switch on it that switches between programming and UART mode. Something like [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/322466871464). It makes working with the ESP-01 much simpler - you can directly use your PC to set it up right for your system, and even upgrade the firmware (or program it directly with a sketch from the Arduino IDE if you install the right core) with minimum hassle.

Comment: many ESP's default to 74880 baud

Comment: Thank you a lot, I solved setting  ESPserial.begin(115200);